# VBA codes not running after re-installed windows10

Tags: excel, vba

I have already run these codes successfully more than 200 times as I download files on daily basis.
Also having another copies of same code in different drives as reference in case of any issue.

Last night I re-installed my Win10 and office 2019 pro plus both are updated to latest.
And now the codes are not running.

I am not a hard core programmer, not able to understand what's wrong with them. Do I need to install any reference library or .net framework or something else.

The codes stopped at
"Name oldFullName As newfullname"
2 files are there do be downloaded and renamed

The codes get 1st file successfully but, do not rename it so not going to 2nd loop to download 2nd file and to further rename that.

```
    Public IsExit       As Boolean
Global Path         As String

Private Sub Download_AllZip()
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Downloads").Range("C3").Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    Application.EnableEvents = FALSE

    Dim LR          As Long
    Dim Fileurl     As String, Filename As String, y As String, z As String        'msg as string
    Dim r           As Long
    LR = Sheets("Downloads").Range("C6").Row

    For r = 5 To LR

        Fileurl = Sheets("Downloads").Range("C" & r).Value

        If InStr(1, Fileurl, ".zip") <> 0 Then
            filepath = Path

        End If
        Dim Obj1    As Object
        Set Obj1 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        Obj1.Open "GET", Fileurl, FALSE
        Obj1.send
        If Obj1.Status = 200 Then
            Set Obj2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            Obj2.Open
            Obj2.Type = 1
            Obj2.Write Obj1.responseBody
            Obj2.SaveToFile (filepath & getfilename(Fileurl)), 2        ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite

            Call UnzipFileRename(filepath & getfilename(Fileurl), filepath, Sheets("Downloads").Range("D" & r).Value)

            Obj2.Close
            y = (y & vbCr & Sheets("Downloads").Range("D" & r).Value & " = Downloaded & Converted To .CSV in " & filepath)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Range("E" & r).Value = "Downloaded"        '/STATUS
        Else
            z = (z & vbCr & Sheets("Downloads").Range("D" & r).Value & " = Failed To Download")
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Range("E" & r).Value = "Failed"        '/STATUS
        End If   
    Next r

End Sub

Function getfilename(filepath As String)
    Dim v_string()  As String
    v_string = Split(filepath, "/")
    getfilename = v_string(UBound(v_string))

End Function

Private Sub UnzipFileRename(zipFullName As Variant, unzipPath As Variant, newName As String)
    Dim ShellApp    As Object, oldFullName As String, newfullname As String, n As Variant
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    '/get file name

    For Each n In ShellApp.Namespace(zipFullName).Items
        a = a + 1
        oldFullName = unzipPath & n.Name
        newfullname = unzipPath & newName
        If a = 1 Then Exit For
    Next n
    '/delete previous version to avoid any issues
    DeleteFile oldFullName
    DeleteFile newfullname
    '/unzip the file
    ShellApp.Namespace(unzipPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zipFullName).Items
    '/rename the file
    Name oldFullName As newfullname
    '/delete zip file
    DeleteFile CStr(zipFullName)

End Sub

Private Sub DeleteFile(PathAndName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill PathAndName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `oldFullName` and `newfullname` in case of the error? And what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: oldFullName = "C:\MyDownloads\cm29APR2020bhav
newFullName = "C:\MyDownloads\BhavNse.csv

The error I am getting is "Run-time error '91':
Object Variable or With block variable not set

Further I just checked The remaining codes running good without  "Private Sub UnzipFileRename" section
So, the problem is with codes under this.

Comment: And you get this error exactly in this line? `Name oldFullName As newfullname` I cannot see how this line can throw this kind of error. Please clarify.

Comment: as I run codes, I get Run-time error 91 through a message box and when I click on debug the cursor goes to ShellApp.Namespace(unzipPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zipFullName).Items (highlighted with yellow color)

Comment: That makes much more sense now. So what is the value of `unzipPath` and `zipFullName` then? And why are these variables `Variant` and not `String`? • Also make sure that the zip file and the unzip path are in the same folder (I think I remember some issue if this is not the case, so check that).

Comment: will show u everything in a clear way just in 10-15mins

Comment: Pls have a look
I am sure there is nothing missing and it was working before 2 days.
I have not changed the codes, even a single space or dot

https://youtu.be/ZgkwN9jT9DM

Comment: If you don't anwser the questions people here ask, we cannot help you. Help us to help you by giving us the information we ask for. Please re-check my last comment.

Comment: hi,
Already tried interchanging variant to string but, issue remains same.
and zip file and unzip path is in same folder

thanks

Comment: Still missing the values of `unzipPath` and `zipFullName` here. Since these are the only variabes included in this statement something there must be wrong. We cannot tell what unless we know what's their value.